# RequiedIf not working on clint side in mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, customvalidator

I am working on custom validation in mvc. I am using requiredif attribute. It’s working on server side but not on client side.

RequiredIfAttribute.cs

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        protected RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

        public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
        public object TargetValue { get; set; }

        public bool AllowEmptyStrings
        {
            get
            {
                return _innerAttribute.AllowEmptyStrings;
            }
            set
            {
                _innerAttribute.AllowEmptyStrings = value;
            }
        }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
        {
            _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
            DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
            TargetValue = targetValue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
            // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
            var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            var field = containerType.GetProperty(DependentProperty);

            if (field != null)
            {
                // get the value of the dependent property
                var dependentValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                // trim spaces of dependent value
                if (dependentValue != null && dependentValue is string)
                {
                    dependentValue = (dependentValue as string).Trim();

                    if (!AllowEmptyStrings && (dependentValue as string).Length == 0)
                    {
                        dependentValue = null;
                    }
                }

                // compare the value against the target value
                if ((dependentValue == null && TargetValue == null) ||
                    (dependentValue != null && (TargetValue.Equals("*") || dependentValue.Equals(TargetValue))))
                {
                    // match => means we should try validating this field
                    //if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                    if(value==null)
                        // validation failed - return an error
                        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        //public virtual IEnumerable&lt;ModelClientValidationRule&gt; GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        //{

        //}

        private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            // build the ID of the property
            string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(DependentProperty);
            // unfortunately this will have the name of the current field appended to the beginning,
            // because the TemplateInfo's context has had this fieldname appended to it. Instead, we
            // want to get the context as though it was one level higher (i.e. outside the current property,
            // which is the containing object, and hence the same level as the dependent property.
            var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
            if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
                // strip it off again
                depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
            return depProp;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        //IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                ValidationType = "requiredif",
            };

            string depProp = BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext);

            // find the value on the control we depend on;
            // if it's a bool, format it javascript style 
            // (the default is True or False!)
            string targetValue = (TargetValue ?? "").ToString();
            if (TargetValue is bool)
                targetValue = targetValue.ToLower();

            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", depProp);
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", targetValue);

            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

requiredif.js

```
$(function () {
    alert('hii');
    $.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {
            alert(value);
            var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];
            alert(id);

            // get the target value (as a string, 
            // as that's what actual value will be)
            var targetvalue = parameters['targetvalue'];
            targetvalue = (targetvalue == null ? '' : targetvalue).toString();

            // get the actual value of the target control
            // note - this probably needs to cater for more 
            // control types, e.g. radios
            var control = $(id);
            var controltype = control.attr('type');
            var actualvalue =
                (controltype === 'checkbox' || controltype === 'radio') ?
                control.attr('checked').toString() :
                control.val();

            // if the condition is true, reuse the existing 
            // required field validator functionality
            if ($.trim(targetvalue) === $.trim(actualvalue) || ($.trim(targetvalue) === '*' && $.trim(actualvalue) !== ''))
                return $.validator.methods.required.call(
                  this, value, element, parameters);

            return true;
        });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'requiredif',
        ['dependentproperty', 'targetvalue'],
        function (options) {
            options.rules['requiredif'] = {
                dependentproperty: options.params['dependentproperty'],
                targetvalue: options.params['targetvalue']
            };
            options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
        });
});
```

Model

```
        [Required]
        public bool IsFeederSelected { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("IsFeederSelected", true, ErrorMessage = "You must enter purchase date")]
        [Display(Name = "Meter Name")]
        public List<string> SelectedMeterName { get; set; }
```

I would like to know how I can achieve the same, any small inputs on the same is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific problem you have at client side, what is the error? Are properties like `data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty` generated on your `SelectedMeterName` field in html?

Comment: No error on occoured but the validation message was not display.  and my generated html is                                                                  
                                                                                                       
<select id="ddlMeterCons" style="width: 100%; display: none;" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose Feeders.." data-val="true" data-val-requiredif="You must enter purchase date" data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="IsFeederSelected" data-val-requiredif-targetvalue="true" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedMeterName">

Comment: ok, just to check in your validator `addMethod` try return `false` in your first line and see if you get error message. Also, I see in html your dropdown is `display:none`

Comment: When I return false in addMethod no error message will display.

Comment: 'display:none' for choosen dropdown list.

Comment: Any success? Try removing `$(function () {`. Your alerts in `addmethod` are working right?

Comment: Not working sir

Comment: A bit late to reply... How do you load this view? Using ajax load method?